# IOS bulk push notification

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have created an application that send push notifications for IOS handsets, and the application is sending the push successfully to 1 user at a time.
The problem occurs when sending the push to about 100k user at a time(of course a big delay will occur on the handsets, since I am looping the device tokens in order to send the push one by one).

So because of this delay, I don't want to loop my DataTable. I need to send all the notifications to all the device tokens instantly, so the devices get the push notifications at the same time without any delay.

Is there any way to do it ?
NB: I am using C#. If another language can achieve and solve this issue,please advice.

Answer (score 2):

You have no control over when the devices get the push notifications. Even if you managed to submit your 100k push notifications to the APNS server instantly, the speed in which they are actually delivered to the devices depends on the APNS server.

If you are asking how to submit 100k push notifications to the APNS server instantly, you can improve your speed by opening multiple sockets to the APNS server and sending the notifications in multiple threads. Even when you send the notifications one by one, assuming that you are using the same connection and not closing and opening the socket all the time, they are batched in the TCP level by default, so they reach the APNS server in batches.

Comment: So based on your reply, there is noway to send several token device in the same request. Right ?

Comment: @AndroidNabz If by the same request you mean an array of bytes that holds multiple device tokens and just one payload, then no, there is no way. For each device token, you must include the payload (and the other fields, such as expiration and message ID).

Comment: So weird that in the same payload I cannot put an array of device tokens; contrary to android. Anyway, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [PushSharp](https://github.com/redth/pushsharp) library. It will manage the opening & closing of multiple sockets for you. It also has feedback implemented, so you will know if any push failed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi. This is possible to send single push messages to multiple devices in single request. I did the r&d and implement the code ready and tested with 5-10 devices.